# Awarding a bounty to myself

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I noticed that I had the button to award a bounty even on my own answer, so I couldn't resist and awarded the bounty to myself, just to see what happens. The result is that the bounty is awarded, but I did not get any reputation for myself.

It makes sense that you don't get reputation for your own bounty, but I think the option to award it should not be there in the first place.

The option also appeared for answers posted before the bounty was started, I thought a bounty could only be awarded for new answers?

Comment: See: [I just awarded myself a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54998/54262)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- bounties can be awarded to all answers, including your own. :) However, as you discovered, you cannot get your rep back no matter what. [Read more.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty)

If you have further questions about how the site works -- [we have a Q&A site for that!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: So it is an intended behaviour. To me it is like a big red button that says 'destroy universe', I just wanted to see what happens.

Comment: @Fabian somehow the universe failed to end, maybe this is a bug indeed :(

Comment: Rules contradict here, if a bounty is awarded, it is added to reputation of getter. If asker himself is the person who deserves the bounty why not award him?
[I awarded a bounty to my question after i found the answer myself](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14547/soldier-of-fortune-payback-white-screen-when-i-run "soldier-of-fortune-payback-white-screen-when-i-run")

Comment: @LifeH20 That's not a bounty, that's an accepted answer. Incidentally, a self-accept  doesn't give you the +2 for answer acceptance, the +15 for accepted answer or the bump accepted answers have in the ordering.